# Does a standing wave on a path have different free energy than a traveling wave?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

My somewhat naïve view is that the standing wave is "bound" to its path, and thus higher in free energy than a traveling wave of equivalent amplitude and wavelength. But I'm not sure how accurate this actually is, or if a free energy analysis can even be applied to waves (perhaps there's a better framework that I'm unaware of).

For the purpose of this question this would be an electromagnetic wave in a vacuum, either traveling in a straight line or in a perfect circle. The linear wave has amplitude, wavelength, and a direction of motion, while the wave moving in a circle has all of these and a constantly changing angular velocity.